# Manually passing BLOB as input paramter from java byte array

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, blob, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a byte array in JAVA where it resembles BLOB object obtained from the database.

This byte array shall be passed to another database function (which is done by the ojdbc driver automatically) when the database function is called from java.

The problem here is that I am trying to debug the database function manually through SQLDeveloper. What I have while debugging through JAVA is the byte array.

I couldn't find a way to manually convert this byte array to a compatible BLOB object that can be passed as an input parameter to the explicit function call in SQLDeveloper PL/SQL.

Is there a way to convert the byte array manually to a BLOB object that I can pass to the function?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to create a temporary BLOB insert the data into it and use it as the bind value to your function. A CLOB/BLOB (at least for Oracle) is just a locator to data in the Database. It doesn't contain any data, just a pointer to the data.

Comment: Thank you @Jean. This was one of the options while discussing solutions with some colleagues.. I was wondering if there is a better practice.. let us wait a bit and see..